# Laravel Flysystem WebDav list directory

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, webdav, flysystem

I'm trying to get list of directory on WebDav through Flysystem however is it empty. I'm using Laravel Graham's Campbell integration of Flysystem:

```
dump(Flysystem::listContents('test'));
```

gives me empty array while

```
dump(Flysystem::read('/test/test2.txt'));
```

gives me content of file.

Could you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!