# How to get the list of files in the WEBDAV directory with Flysystem?

Tags: php, laravel, webdav, flysystem

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993733/laravel-flysystem-webdav-list-directory) on stackoverflow but noone answered there.

So I'am trying to get the list of files from the WEBDAV cloud storage using [laravel-flysystem framework](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem) that is based on [Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/). I did everything according to manual and everything is working perfectly except one function - [listContents()](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/).

Here is an example of my code

```
var_dump(Flysystem::read('/test/test.txt'));
var_dump(Flysystem::listContents('/test/'));
```

This code returns the following:

```
string(4) "123"
array(0) {
}
```

I have *test.txt* file in the *test/* directory and read() function return's it's content but listContents() function don't return the file.

Can someone please explain what can be done to get the list of files from the directory? Thanks.

Comment: Want to add that I already tried to set $recursive both on true and false with no changes. I also tried different moves with '\' - it was no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now as a temporary solution I had to change the code in vendor. An awful decision but I don't plan to use composer in this project for the time and just for reinsurance I locked the version of *league/flysystem* in composer.json

So as a solution I went to *vendor/league/flysystem/src/Util/ContentListingFormatter.php*
(it exist in 1.0.57 version of *league/flysystem* for shure). In function *isDirectChild()* you need to `return true;` . This way you will get an array of actual files from your webdav directory instead of an empty array.

I really hope that this bug will be fixed someday.